# What is the limit of this indicator function: $\lim_{c\to \infty} 1_{x\leq \frac1c}$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

What would be the limit of this function

$$\lim_{c\to \infty} 1_{x\leq \frac{1}{c}}.$$

I think the answer would be : $1_{x\leq 0}$. But not sure. Please throw me some light whether I am correct or wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Well, what should the limit value be for, let's say, $x = 0.1$? What about $x = 0$? What about $x = -1$?

Comment: What definition of limit you are using? There are several different definitions of convergence for functions, e.g. pointwise, uniformely, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f_c:= 1_{\{x\leq \frac{1}{c}\}}$ and let $x \in \mathbb R$.

Case 1: $x \le 0$. Then $f_c(x)=1$ for all $c>0$, hence

$\lim_{c \to \infty}f_c(x)=1.$

Case 2: $x>0$. Then there is $c_0>0$ such that $x>\frac{1}{c_0}$ we then have: $x>\frac{1}{c}$ for all $c>c_0$ and hence $f_c(x)=0$ for all $c>c_0$.

This gives

$\lim_{c \to \infty}f_c(x)=0$.

Comment: According to your answer the limit is finally : $1_{x\leq 0}$. Am I correct ?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

For $x\le0$, there is no doubt, because $0\le1/c$ and $1_{x\le0}=1_{x\le1/c}=1$.

Then for $x>0$, for large enough $c$ we can ensure $x>1/c$ and $1_{x\le0}=1_{x\le1/c}=0$.

---

The situation would be different with $1_{x<1/c}$.

Because for $x\ge0$, we cannot ensure $x\ge1/c$, and

$$\lim_{c\to \infty} 1_{x<\frac{1}{c}}=1_{x\leq 0}.$$